# Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline with aws codepipeline using serverless framework and aws lambda gets success but does not create lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, bitbucket, serverless-framework

serverless.yml file

```
service: test-apis

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
```

bitbucket-pipeline.yml

```
version: 0.1

pipelines:
  default: # any branch except defined branch below e.g feature br
   - step:
        script:
          - npm ci
          - npm test
          - npm run lint
  branches:
    development: # development branch
      - step:
          script:
            - npm ci
            - npm test
            - npm run lint
     - step:
          # Build and package the Lambda function.
          name: Build and package
          script:
            - $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/scripts/script.sh default
            - serverless deploy --stage dev
```

script.sh

```
PROFILE=$1
apt-get update && apt-get install -y python python-dev python-pip
pip install awscli
npm install -g serverless
npm ci
aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --profile $PROFILE
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --profile $PROFILE
aws configure set $PROFILE.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
export AWS_PROFILE=$PROFILE
```

Logs

```
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:12 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:16 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:19 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:19 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src008385171/src/bitbucket.org/betaflux/test-apis
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:19 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src008385171/src/bitbucket.org/betaflux/test-apis/bitbucket-pipeline.yml
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:19 Found possible syntax errors in buildspec: 
    The following keys cannot be identified:
        pipelines
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:19 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 No runtime version selected in buildspec.
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src008385171/src/bitbucket.org/betaflux/test-apis
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Registering with agent
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phases found in YAML: 0
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/05/03 13:12:20 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

When I try to pipeline bitbucket with aws codepipeline, it gets success but lambda function is not created. I am using serverless framework but it doesnt work. There are no error message in logs but also no output as well. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It says `Found possible syntax errors in buildspec: The following keys cannot be identified: pipelines` which indicates that AWS CodeBuild doesn't understand the `yml` you're trying to use. Which makes sense because it's a Bitbucket-Pipeline. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but to my knowledge Bitbucket-Pipeline and AWS CodeBuild are different CI/CD systems and you can't mix them, you'll need to write a new `yml` for AWS CodeBuild.

Comment: @yvesonline I want to setup bitbucket CI/CD pipeline with aws codebuild. When I push any changes to bitbucket I want it to configure aws services. for eg I am using lambda functions using serverless framwork and also dynamodb so when I push any changes to bitbucket it should reflect to codebuild and should create lambda functions for me